# IMPORTXML value returned price NOT as number - need help to convert

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Not an expert in Google sheet so would appreciate if someone can help me solve this:

trying to do some work on crypto pricing.
I extract the actual price this way
CELL I2 has something like https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/AAVE
If I use formula =IMPORTXML(I2,"//div[@class='priceValue ']")
It will return the price value of the I2 crypto in this case for example $320.12
It seems the 320.12 is text and I could not convert to number using VALUE(I2)

I need to use this 320.12 to calculate ...
for example I try to multiply the 320.12 by the quantity and I get the error: Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But '$320.12' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Appreciate the help

Comment: You can try to convert the value to a numeric value by substituting a dot for a comma. `=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(I2,"//div[@class='priceValue ']"),".",",")*1`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=1*REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(I2, "//div[@class='priceValue ']")&"", "\d+.\d+|\d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

No the value is a number formatted in $, you can use it ... see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cgb8D01AR7Zy6FVjYcVtJkNk1lEtRC7V_UvjcF283qA/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to use the same as your file but still having the same issue:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14tadSKv4S3uv25a7BgUYoflKYGPfcbNxNXIni-JV4Wg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: access denied, pls share your spreadsheet

Comment: because your locale is GB and not US, so try `=C2*substitute(F2,"$","")`